# AWS S3 Presigned URL with other query parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I create a pre-signed URL and get back something like

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/MyBucket/MyItem/
?X-Amz-Security-Token=TOKEN
&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
&X-Amz-Date=20171206T014837Z
&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host
&X-Amz-Expires=3600
&X-Amz-Credential=CREDENTIAL
&X-Amz-Signature=SIGNATURE
```

I can now `curl` this no problem. However, if I now add another query parameter, I will get back a 403, i.e.

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/MyBucket/MyItem/
?X-Amz-Security-Token=TOKEN
&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
&X-Amz-Date=20171206T014837Z
&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host
&X-Amz-Expires=3600
&X-Amz-Credential=CREDENTIAL
&X-Amz-Signature=SIGNATURE
&Foo=123
```

How come? Is it possible to generate a pre-signed url that supports custom queries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you change one of the headers or add / subtract, then you have to resign the URL.

This is part of the AWS signing design and this process is designed for higher levels of security. One of the AWS reasons for changing to signing version 4 from signing version 2.

The signing design does not know which headers are important and which are not. That would create a nightmare trying to track all of the AWS services.

Answer (score 8):

It seems to be technically feasible to insert custom query parameters into a v4 pre-signed URL, *before* it is signed, but not all of the AWS SDKs expose a way to do this.

Here's an example of a roundabout way to do this with the AWS JavaScript SDK:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

var s3 = new AWS.S3({region: 'us-east-1', signatureVersion: 'v4'});
var req = s3.getObject({Bucket: 'mybucket', Key: 'mykey'});
req.on('build', () => { req.httpRequest.path += '?session=ABC123'; });
console.log(req.presign());
```

I've tried this with custom query parameters that begin with X- and without it. Both appeared to work fine. I've tried with multiple query parameters (`?a=1&b=2`) and that worked too.

The customized pre-signed URLs work correctly (I can use them to get S3 objects) and the query parameters make it into CloudWatch Logs so can be used for correlation purposes.

Note that if you want to supply a custom expiration time, then do it as follows:

```
const Expires = 120;
const url = req.presign(Expires);
```

I'm not aware of other (non-JavaScript) SDKs that allow you to insert query parameters into the URL construction process like this so it may be a challenge to do this in other languages. I'd recommend using a small JavaScript Lambda function (or API Gateway plus Lambda function) that would simply create and return the customized pre-signed URL.

The custom query parameters are also tamper-proof. They are included in the signing of the URL so, if you tamper with them, the URL becomes invalid, yielding 403 Forbidden.

I used this code to generate your pre-signed URL. The result was:

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/MyBucket/MyItem
?Foo=123
&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
&X-Amz-Credential=AKIA...27%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request
&X-Amz-Date=20180427T0012345Z
&X-Amz-Expires=3600
&X-Amz-Signature=e3...7b
&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host
```

None of this is a guarantee that this technique will continue to work, of course, if AWS changes things under the covers but for right now it seems to work and is certainly useful.

Attribution: the source of this discovery was [aws-sdk-js/issues/502](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/502).

Comment: Thank you @jarmod  , its almost 3 years and this still works.....

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking on for JavaScript SDK V3:

```
import { HttpRequest } from "@aws-sdk/protocol-http";
import { S3RequestPresigner } from "@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner";
import { parseUrl } from "@aws-sdk/url-parser";
import { Sha256 } from "@aws-crypto/sha256-browser";
import { Hash } from "@aws-sdk/hash-node";
import { formatUrl } from "@aws-sdk/util-format-url";

// Make custom query in Record<string, string | Array<string> | null> format
const customQuery = {
  hello: "world",
};

const s3ObjectUrl = parseUrl(
  `https://${bucketName}.s3.${region}.amazonaws.com/${key}`
);
s3ObjectUrl.query = customQuery; //Insert custom query here

const presigner = new S3RequestPresigner({
  credentials,
  region,
  sha256: Hash.bind(null, "sha256"), // In Node.js
  //sha256: Sha256 // In browsers
});

// Create a GET request from S3 url.
const url = await presigner.presign(new HttpRequest(s3ObjectUrl));
console.log("PRESIGNED URL: ", formatUrl(url));
```

Code template taken from: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/generate-presigned-url-modular-aws-sdk-javascript/

Comment: That documentation is poor.  There is no explanation as to how one can change / update the expiration of the presigned URL generated by S3RequestPresigner.

Comment: For expiration, add option to presign call as follows:

```
const url = await presigner.presign(new HttpRequest(s3ObjectUrl), {
      expiresIn: 400,
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I created this solution for Ruby SDK. It is sort of a hack, but it works as expected:

```rb
require 'aws-sdk-s3'
require 'active_support/core_ext/object/to_query.rb'

# Modified S3 pre signer class that can inject query params to the URL
#
# Usage example:
#
#    bucket_name = "bucket_name"
#    key = "path/to/file.json"
#    filename = "download_file_name.json"
#    duration = 3600
#
#    params = {
#      bucket: bucket_name,
#      key: key,
#      response_content_disposition: "attachment; filename=#{filename}",
#      expires_in: duration
#    }
#
#    signer = S3PreSignerWithQueryParams.new({'x-your-custom-field': "banana", 'x-some-other-field': 1234})
#    url = signer.presigned_url(:get_object, params)
#
#    puts "url = #{url}"
#
class S3PreSignerWithQueryParams < Aws::S3::Presigner
  def initialize(query_params = {}, options = {})
    @query_params = query_params
    super(options)
  end

  def build_signer(cfg)
    signer = super(cfg)
    my_params = @query_params.to_h.to_query()
    signer.define_singleton_method(:presign_url,
                                   lambda do |options|
                                     options[:url].query += "&" + my_params
                                     super(options)
                                   end)
    signer
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks @DavidRissatoCruz. I am trying to give this a shot but not seeing my code hit the build_signer method - looking at the source docs and trying to trace it through and am wondering if there's anything else I should include?

Answer (score 0):

While not documented, you can add parameters as arguments to the call to `presigned_url`.

```rb
obj.presigned_url(:get, 
  expires_in: expires_in_sec, 
  response_content_disposition: "attachment"
)
```

```
https://bucket.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/file.txt?response-content-disposition=attachment&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=PUBLICKEY%2F20220309%2Fus-east-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220309T031958Z&X-Amz-Expires=43200&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=SIGNATUREVALUE
```

Comment: do you know where's the documentation for the parameters we can use?