# Allow unknown key value pairs in S3 pre signed URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I have an use case where i want to generate S3 pre signed URL for a given object key but want the URL to work if some random request parameters are added to it. Is there a way to do this using GeneratePresignedUrlRequest from AWS Java SDK or some other class in the SDK?

**Example**

If my pre signed URL is http://test.s3.amazonaws.com/sdfasdlkfjsd and i request for http://test.s3.amazonaws.com/sdfasdlkfjsd?random=100&random=200, i still want to be able to download that content ignoring the random request parameter. Currently, i get this instead

```
<Error>
    <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
    <Message>
        The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
    </Message>
    ....
</Error>
```

Comment: Why are these query parameters being added?  
I don't think this is possible as the AWS V4 Signing Process uses the query string parameter as part of canonical request which is hashed and compared when the actual request is made.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-canonical-request.html.

Answer (score 1):

Pre-signed URLs are designed to be tamper-resistant.  Any modification that changes the elements of the URL invalidates the signature.  That's by design, and unrelated to any limitation in the Java SDK.

You can of course add the custom values *before* signing the URL. The [S3 access log documentation recommends these begin with `x-`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/LogFormat.html#LogFormatCustom) and the V4 signing algorithm definitely supports it, but it is not clear how you would do this with the Java SDK.  With the JavaScript SDK, there's [a simple hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50053514/1695906) involving the event hooks.

Alternately, put CloudFront in front of the bucket. 
 CloudFront pre-signed URLs using custom polices support  [wildcards in the `Resource` field](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-creating-signed-url-custom-policy.html#private-content-custom-policy-statement-values), which is the field where the full URL is specified, in the custom policy.