# Upload file to s3 with additional parameter in the query string

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I followed [this doc](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-upload-image-s3/) in order to upload file using postman into s3 storage. All good but

> How can I expand this amazon api gateway with query string
> `?isValid=true`

Comment: What is your intention with adding `?isValid=true`? What are you hoping this will do?

Comment: In the api gateway my PUT action is integrated with AWS service (S3) and it stores file (from the request) into s3 storage. From the other side my lambda function will be triggered from this S3 change. Here I want to access this isValid property. Now when I wrote all this I guess it must be a better way for this? Basically I want to upload file to S3 and depending on isValid property I want to trigger my lambda function.

Comment: It doesn't work that way afaik. You're indicating an S3 key in the API Gateway URL which dictates the key of the uploaded object. Any Lambda function subsequently triggered by that upload will include the key and the bucket associated with the object. It won't include the original uploading client's HTTP headers or query parameters afaik. You might be able to do what you want if you use two key prefixes e.g. `folder1/dogs/a.png` and `folder2/dogs/b.png` and configure S3 event triggers to only trigger Lambda on the prefix `folder1`.

Comment: @jarmod, thanks. Please post this as an answer and include any resources I can look further.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that appending query parameters such as `?isValid=true` to a URL presented to API Gateway when using [API Gateway as an S3 Proxy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html#api-items-in-folder-as-s3-objects-in-bucket) will work.

You're indicating an S3 key in the API Gateway URL which dictates the key of the uploaded object. Any Lambda function subsequently triggered by that upload will include the key and the bucket associated with the object. It won't include the original uploading client's HTTP headers or query parameters afaik.

One option to consider distinguishing between these two use cases (isValid=true and isValid=false) is to use two key prefixes e.g. `valid/dogs/a.png` and `invalid/dogs/b.png` (or even two distinct S3 buckets). You can then configure S3 event triggers to only trigger Lambda on the appropriate uploads (e.g. with prefix `valid/`).

Also, be aware of the possibility of using S3 pre-signed URLs which can include [custom query parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50053514/271415). These custom parameters end up in CloudWatch Logs and so you can potentially trigger custom behavior based on those logs.